# Is it possible to make a simple Discord bot using Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, bots, discord

So I am trying to build a simple system in a music discord where a command is sent to rate a song (i.e `!rate 8.5 Led Zepplin - Immigrant Song`), and the bot (which should be written in Google Apps Script, not Javascript) will edit a Google Sheets spreadsheet by adding the user's username in a new column if the user has never rated before, adding the song in a new row if it has never been rated before, and adding the user's rating in the correct row and column.  Later on, a webpage will take the data from the sheet and display it on the site, but I already have this part figured out.  I've seen a bot on the discord that sends a message whenever a new row is added, but I'm not sure if it can do the reverse: add a row whenever a message is sent.  Is there any way I can do this that you know of?  Does discord.js/discord API work with google apps script? Thanks!

If this is just as possible in Javascript, please do inform me!

I'm tagging this as Javascript too just because Apps Script is so incredibly similar syntactically and because it's possible this is just a simple job for JS  to take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps Script does not run continuously, so you cannot do anything that requires a "presence". JavaScript, on the other hand, can run as long as you wish in the environment you give it (e.g. node.js) so you can absolutely run bots with it.

Comment: Well, I realize that a bot can be made using Javascript, as I have done this before.  What I am asking then is Can Javascript edit a google spreadsheet?

Comment: @jodast of course. Any language that has a way to send an http request can. Do more research.

Comment: @Jodast Webapps are constantly online. It has a presence and you probably just need to create a webhook to apps script on message sent trigger.